# Re-using AudioTrack instances

Tags: android, memory-leaks, native

We've encountered the memory leak in the AudioTrack class (http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17995)

Is there anyway to re-use AudioTrack instances with different waveform data?
The AudioTracks need to be in static mode for low latency.

We basically want allocate (for example) 16 AudioTrack instances and re-use them whenever we play some sound-fx. The problem seems to be writing to an AudioTrack that has been used causes a crash, even if the AudioTrack has been stopped.

Anyone care to help up out please? Is what I'm trying to do even possible?

Thank you,

Steve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>If you are trying to use a limited number of tracks have you tried using static mode?</strike>

From @Steve Haggerty's comment below: there is reportedly a memory leak in certain versions of Android, and STREAM mode is to be preferred for all development work.

Comment: We are using static mode.

Can I set up AudioTracks in static mode and re-use the SAME AudioTracks with different audio data. Because at the moment, if I try to write to an AudioTrack that has already been played with DIFFERENT data, I get a crash.

Steve.

Comment: Yeah, you can't change the data in a static track: you can reload it to replay, but that's it. If you have a limited number of tracks do you NEED to use different data, can't you just generate a Track for each audio file and reuse those?

Comment: Got an email back from Google. There is a  memory leak in the STATIC stuff. You should use STREAM mode for all audio. The latency will be negligible even in stream mode.

Comment: Good to know: I'll strike the answer.